# hide download url of files on a download server

Tags: php, url, download, hide

I have a php code on one server and a set of files on a download server. the download server is unable to run any php or other types of script. I want to make a download page on php server to download specific files on the download server but hide the file path on the download server. also I have traffic matter so I don't want the php server to get the whole of the file from the download server and make another temporary link for it to download because this make lots of traffic on the php server. how can i resolve this problem? is there any way to use client side safe scripts like js?

Comment: `http://example.com/download.php?id=7`, then have that php script suck in/spit out whatever file you wanted to be downloaded.

Comment: Even if you use a client-end solution to obfuscate the absolute path, it will still be visible for people who dig a bit.  Without running PHP(or any scripting for that matter) on the file server, and without reading the data to your PHP enabled server, I don't see much of an option.

Comment: The only way to hide the link to the download server is to stream the file through the PHP server and deny external access to the download server entirely.  It's not going to be very efficient, since the PHP server is going to have to both upload and download every file, doubling its network usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can you the php read function for example:
        //specify content type
        header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
           readfile('pathtoyourfile')